# How to measure computing time

Tags: c, time

In my homework assignment I am supposed to measure computation time for different algorithms. I am given the following functions "beginTime" and "endTime" to do it. However, when I compile them, together with my algorithm, the compiler shows that "start" and "stop" are undefined. But I don't know how to define them (what type they should be), and how to make the "start" in "endTime" refer to the "start" in "beginTime". How can I fix it? Also, how can I print the returned value?

```
 void
beginTime ()
{
gettimeofday (&start, 0);
}

float
endTime ()
{
gettimeofday (&stop, 0);

double begin = (double) start.tv_sec + (double) (start.tv_usec / 1.E6);

double end = (double) stop.tv_sec + (double) (stop.tv_usec / 1.E6);

return end - begin;
}
```

Comment: Using `float` for `endTime()` is going to start throwing away microseconds as soon as you run the timer for longer than about 10 seconds.  You almost certainly need to use `double`, not `float`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: `float` suffices. The actual calculations are performed with `double`. Only the result is converted to `float`. Likely a homework assignment does not require measuring the total time with relative precision greater than 2**-23.

Answer (score 3):

If you look up the function [`gettimeofday`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday), you'll see it takes `struct timeval`.  Your code should look like this:

```
#include <sys/time.h>

static struct timeval start, stop;

void beginTime()
{
    gettimeofday (&start, 0);
}

float endTime()
{
    gettimeofday (&stop, 0);
    double begin = (double) start.tv_sec + (double) (start.tv_usec / 1.E6);
    double end = (double) stop.tv_sec + (double) (stop.tv_usec / 1.E6);
    return end - begin;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [man page for `gettimeofday()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday) lists the relevant type:

```
struct timeval {
    time_t      tv_sec;     /* seconds */
    suseconds_t tv_usec;    /* microseconds */
};
```

You'll have to save `start` somewhere. The worst-case scenario (since this is a homework assignment) might be to just make it a global variable. In a production environment, your `beginTime()` function would actually return a `double` for the starting time, which you would simply record before running the algorithm you are trying to time.